# Instamojo payment gateway integration with ios objective c webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, instamojo

Does anyobody know how to integrate instamojo payment gateway in objective C. I have opened Instamojo payment screen in Webview but how to handle success of payment and redirect to app.

Comment: follow this : https://docs.instamojo.com/page/ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

HI Manish for payment gateways

1. You need to create Merchant account. For Merchant account you need to login in Instamojo.
2. After creation of Merchant account, they will provide keys and SDKs(iOS, android). You need to download that SDK and integrate that in your app. Use that key in AppDelegate Class. They will provide a sample code how to use the keys, SDK and how to do the payments. Follow the instructions.

Comment: Seems, Instamojo not supporting swift 3. Not getting method which are shown in document

Comment: Call to support team of Instamojo. They will tell you, is they are giving support to swift?.